# Vertical-center UIImageView with snapkit

Tags: swift, snapkit

How can I vertical-center a UIImageView in super view with the snapkit?
I tried like this:

```
 imageview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(view.center.y);

        }
```

but seems not well.How can I use the snapkit

Comment: I guess you forgot to add `make.centerX.equalTo(view.center.x)` part. And there are still 2 other constraints needed - `width` and `height`. Because it knows where the center should be. But does not know how big should be your image view

Comment: make.centerY.equalTo(view.center.y); just make the button of the imageview in the vertical-center of its superview

Answer (score 11):

Try following code

```
Imageview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
     make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left).offset(50)
     make.centerY.equalTo(self.view)
     make.width.height.equalTo(100)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to give the imageView a centerY only , you need to give it also width,height and x constraint , so try this

```
imageview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left).offset(50)
      make.centerY.equalTo(self.view)
      make.width.height.equalTo(100)
}
```

Comment: you should specify width , heigth and x constraint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set imageView in center of its superview with size of 100x100 then try below code;

```
imageview.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.centerY.centerX.equalToSuperview()
    make.height.width.equalTo(100) 
}
```

If you want to set imageView in vertial-center and with 50px offset from leading edge of its superview with size of 100x100 then try below code;

```
imgView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    make.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
    make.height.width.equalTo(100)
}
```